# Compilation error on using dependent scope as type for std::less in default argument

Tags: c++, templates, stl

The following piece of monstrosity was working fine before I added the second argument to make it more generic:

```
template<class IterableType, class Comparator>
typename IterableType::iterator GetMinimum(IterableType collection, Comparator comparator =
        std::less<typename IterableType::iterator>
        )
{
    typename IterableType::iterator iter = collection.begin();
    typename IterableType::iterator result = iter;

    for(; iter != collection.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if(comparator(iter, result))
            result = iter;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Currently it gives the following error:

```
121:9: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

for the line numbers:

```
118: template<class IterableType, class Comparator>
119: typename IterableType::iterator GetMinimum(IterableType collection, Comparator comparator =
120:         std::less<typename IterableType::iterator>
121:         )
```

I have #included `<functional>` so `std::less` is valid. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to say

```
Comparator comparator = std::less<typename IterableType::iterator>()
```

in the argument list, i.e. with the extra brackets on the end to default-construct the `less` object.

But I'm still not sure it would work, as don't think the compiler can deduce the Comparator type like this. **EDIT**: @battery confirms in the comments that this doesn't work.

The right way to do it is to supply `std::less` as a default template argument, and then you can say

```
template <typename IterableType, typename Comparator = std::less<...>>
GetMinimum(IterableType collection, Comparator comparator = Comparator{})
```

and it will default-construct whatever Comparator type the user chooses.

Comment: Thanks Tristan, the first approach worked! I'll try out the other suggestion as well later.

Comment: Sorry, to correct myself, the first approach did not work. This code was part of a shared library and that compiled. But on trying to use the code I did get the error: template argument deduction/substitution failed.
It would be advisable to make an edit and remove the first approach.

Comment: @battery Well, in fairness, I did say I didn't think it would work! It wasn't meant to be either/or -- the second approach is the right way to do it. I'll edit the answer in case anyone else comes across this question in future.

Answer (score 2):

`std::less<...>` is a type. You need to instantiate it if you want to use it as the default value of an argument, i.e., `std::less<...>()`.

However, this approach is not going to work anyway, because the compiler cannot deduce a template parameter using the default value of an argument. The way the STL deals with this is just by overloading the function, providing one template that takes an extra comparator argument, and another that doesn't (and just uses `std::less`). For example, see [std::max_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/)

Answer (score 1):

The signature should be:

```
template<
    class IterableType,
    class Comparator = std::less<typename IterableType::iterator> >
typename IterableType::iterator
GetMinimum(IterableType collection, Comparator comparator)
```

Move the default into the template parameters.

And for a default template parameter and a default argument

```
template<
    class IterableType,
    class Comparator = std::less<typename IterableType::iterator> >
typename IterableType::iterator
GetMinimum(
    IterableType collection, Comparator comparator = Comparator() )
```